# pandas: check series for matching values in reference list, generate new record for each match

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with evictions data where each record is an eviction being processed for a specific address. One column shows causes, which can include, among others, non-payment of rent, unauthorized subtenants, owner-move in, building rehabilitation and a number of other causes.

These are all encoded as a string, with each cause sometimes separated by space, other times by comma.

I also have a reference list with all the possible causes. My aim is to match the record-specific reason(s) against the reference list and return a value for each match and then, *for each match*, generate a new duplicate record with the same basic info, but a different cause so that record x may have as many entries as recorded causes for eviction.

Let's say possible eviction causes include

```
causes = ['Breach of Lease Agreement',
 'Capital Improvement',
 'Condo Conversion',
 'Demolition',
 'Demolition Capital Improvement',
 'Denial of Access to Unit',
 'Development Agreement',
 'Ellis Act Withdrawal',
 'Failure to Sign Lease Renewal',
 'Good Samaritan Tenancy Ends',
 'Habitual Late Payment of Rent',
 'Illegal Use of Unit',
 'Lead Remediation',
 'Non-payment of Rent',
 'Nuisance',
 'Other',
 'Owner Move In',
 'Roommate Living in Same Unit',
 'Substantial Rehabilitation',
 'Substantial Rehabilitationr',
 'Unapproved Subtenant']
```

while a few records may look like this (dataframe named `evict`):

```
id      date    stname  city    reason
0    1/4/93  MATEO   SAN FRANCISCO   Owner Move In
1    1/4/93  DIVISADERO  SAN FRANCISCO   Non-payment of Rent Habitual Late Payment of Rent
2    1/4/93  SILLMAN     SAN FRANCISCO   Other
3    1/4/93  8TH     SAN FRANCISCO   Owner Move In
4    1/5/93  DUBOCE  SAN FRANCISCO   Owner Move In
5    1/5/93  MASONIC     SAN FRANCISCO   Non-payment of Rent Nuisance Illegal Use of Unit
6    1/5/93  MASONIC     SAN FRANCISCO   Non-payment of Rent Nuisance
7    1/6/93  DOLPHIN     SAN FRANCISCO   Non-payment of Rent
8    1/6/93  DUBOCE  SAN FRANCISCO   Owner Move In
9    1/7/93  FRANCISCO   SAN FRANCISCO   Owner Move In Nuisance Nuisance
```

I tried running a basic match, like so:

```
pattern = '|'.join(causes)
evict.reason.str.contains(pattern)
```

Which, of course, just returns true if there is any match between the column and reference, but I am interested in 'pulling out' each match and having a repeat record for each cause.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas 0.13+ you can use the [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [11]: pattern = '(%s)' % '|'.join(causes)

In [12]: evict.reason.str.extract(pattern)
Out[12]: 
0          Owner Move In
1    Non-payment of Rent
2                  Other
3          Owner Move In
4          Owner Move In
5    Non-payment of Rent
6    Non-payment of Rent
7    Non-payment of Rent
8          Owner Move In
9          Owner Move In
Name: reason, dtype: object
```

*Note: You have to put it in parenthesis to extract a group.*

Comment: This gets me a good part of the way, but seemingly returns the first match only. But each string might contain several reasons for eviction in the same field. It is those cases of multiple matches where I would like to compare sections against the pattern/reference. I.e. match a string with possibly many sections that might match a reference list of many (albeit concatenated values)

Comment: I think something along these lines might do the trick: `for result in re.finditer(pattern, "Non-payment of Rent Nuisance Illegal Use of Unit"):
    print("".join(result.groups()))`

Comment: @ako Hmmm if these were seperated by something other than space you could use str.get_dummies, you could do something similar with pd.concat((evict.reason.str.contains(c) for c in causes), axis=1, keys=causes)... not quite perfect though some causes are substrings of other causes...

Comment: will try again this weekend, thanks for checking in!

Comment: this non-vectorized version works in splitting out new rows for each match of string elements against those found in `pattern` .`for count, row in evict.iterrows():
    if count<50: 
        reasons = re.findall(pattern2,row.reason)
        for item in reasons:
            print row.RecordID,item`